# Error message" The fix-no-tty provisioner could not be found" when I vagrant up with VVV

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vvvv

I'm currently trying to create a virtual environment for wordpress development. I've installed Git Bash, ConEmu, Virtual Box, Vagrant, Vagrant Host updater, Vagrant triggers, and Varying Vagrant Vagrants. the first time I used vagrant up, I got this message:

default: Successfully added box 'ubuntu/trusty64' (v20150609.0.10) for 'virtualbox'! There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix the following errors and try again:

vm: * The 'fix-no-tty' provisioner could not be found.

I don't really have any idea what this means and have had little success finding information on the internet. Does anyone know what the fix-no-tty provisioner is and how i could fix it?

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same issue today with a new clone of VVV while running Vagrant 1.6.3. The fix-no-tty provisioner was [introduced](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV/commit/b01493e2d4b211c666bb8bbd93557a74939e6d74) on April 29. Named provisioner support [was added](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) to Vagrant in version 1.7.0. I upgraded to Vagrant 1.7.2 and was able to bring the VM up.